# Arithmetic on `isbits` type parameters

Tags: julia

I want a type-stable version of the following (this isn't):

```
foo(::Val{k}) where k = Val{k+1}()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this count?

```
@generated bar(::Val{k}) where k = :(Val{$(k+1)}())
```

For example:

```
julia> bar(Val{2}())
Val{3}()

julia> @code_warntype bar(Val{2}())
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  #unused# <optimized out>

Body:
  begin  # line 1:
      return $(QuoteNode(Val{3}()))
  end::Val{3}
```

Comment: This most definitely counts! Thanks!