# Function inputs - enforce various sized objects with relation

Tags: julia

If I were to make an operation that requires two equally sized tuples, I can simply do this:

```
DoOperation(Var1::NTuple{N,Any}, Var2::NTuple{N,Any}) where {N} = ... <whatever operation you want>.
```

And defining N on both restricts the size.
If I want to force different sizes with a relation known a-priori, for example one tuple is longer by 1 element:

```
DoOperation(Var1::NTuple{N,Any}, Var2::NTuple{N+1,Any}) where {N} = ... <whatever operation you want>.
```

this won't work because there is no method matching +(::TypeVar, ::Int64). However, this suggests to me that it is possible to either define this operation or some other way and make this work.
What is the "correct" (Julia-codex compliant) way of doing this?

Edit: To be clear, I'm not asking specifically for `N+1`, that is just an easy and commonly useful example, I mean `M=f(N)` where in this case `f(N)=N+1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacky workaround would be to simply replace the `NTuple{N+1,Any}` with `Tuple{Any,Vararg{N,Any}}`, as when the last element of a `Tuple` is `Vararg`, the `Vararg` gets expanded “in place” (and in fact you can see below that `NTuple{N,T}` *is* just `Tuple{Vararg{T,N}}`). (I've changed the casing to better adhere to Julia’s standards.)

```
julia> do_operation(var1::NTuple{N,Any}, var2::Tuple{Any,Vararg{Any,N}}) where {N} = (var1, var2)
do_operation (generic function with 1 method)

julia> do_operation((1, 2), (3, 4))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching do_operation(::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, ::Tuple{Int64, Int64})

Closest candidates are:
  do_operation(::Tuple{Vararg{Any, N}}, ::Tuple{Any, Vararg{Any, N}}) where N
   @ Main REPL[33]:1

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[34]:1

julia> do_operation((1, 2), (3, 4, 5))
((1, 2), (3, 4, 5))

julia> do_operation((1, 2), (3, 4, 5, 6))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching do_operation(::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, ::NTuple{4, Int64})

Closest candidates are:
  do_operation(::Tuple{Vararg{Any, N}}, ::Tuple{Any, Vararg{Any, N}}) where N
   @ Main REPL[33]:1

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[36]:1

julia>
```

If you need to enforce an arbitrary expression to hold between the tuple lengths, you can make an assertion in a generated function:

```
julia> f(n) = n^2
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @generated function gen_do_op(var1::NTuple{M,Any}, var2::NTuple{N,Any}) where {M,N}
       @assert N == f(M)
       return :((var1, var2))
       end
gen_do_op (generic function with 1 method)

julia> gen_do_op((1,2), (3,4))
ERROR: AssertionError: N == f(M)
Stacktrace:
 [1] #s78#13
   @ ./REPL[59]:2 [inlined]
 [2] var"#s78#13"(M::Any, N::Any, ::Any, var1::Any, var2::Any)
   @ Main ./none:0
 [3] (::Core.GeneratedFunctionStub)(::Any, ::Vararg{Any})
   @ Core ./boot.jl:602
 [4] top-level scope
   @ REPL[60]:1

julia> gen_do_op((1,2), (3,4,5,6))
((1, 2), (3, 4, 5, 6))
```

The assertion is only triggered when the generated function is *compiled*, not when it's *called*, so from a performance perspective it *shouldn't* be onerous to call the function several times even when `f` is expensive (but note that caching of the compiled function is technically considered an implementation detail; `gen_do_op` *might* be compiled multiple times for the same argument types).

Comment: This is a nice hack, I like it!
However, the N+1 was just a specific example, what about `var1::NTuple{N,Any}, var2::Tuple{M,Any}` with M being a function of N `M=f(N)` and could be anything, lke 2*N or something generic.

Comment: Hmm, you can check if this method words: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441458/arithmetic-on-isbits-type-parameters

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to use the linked approach. Julia doesn't like the expression in the "where" clause...

Comment: Thank you!
I did not want to use the @assert, but I guess it's good enough in this form.

Comment: Also `@assert isequal(length(var2), f(length(var1))` is probably a more generic approach

Comment: just for my personal curiosity, how would one enforce a `M=f(N)` relation on the magnitues of generic input agruments (say `AbstractVector` or `AbstractVecOrTuple`)?
This is sort of expending the question without limiting it to the Tuples hack, and would be useful in dispatching if this can be set (so if N=M it will dispatch one function, if N=M+1 a different one, if N>M+1 another, etc.)